# Arguments not passing from mailer to the html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have defined this mailer service as below. The issue I am facing here is the field values appear in the reminder.html.erb file only if **if expense.expense_url.present?** this case is true. **expense_url** is a field which stores the location of the file. Any idea where am I going wrong?

This issue only happens in the staging server. Localhost prints the email even if the attachment is not present.

mailer.rb

```
require 'open-uri'
class ReminderMailer < ApplicationMailer
    default from: 'abc@yahoo.com', to: ['sid@yahoo.com']
    def reminder(expense_ids)
        @expenses = Expense.where(id: expense_ids)
        @expenses.each do |expense|            
            expense_number = expense.description.split(' ')[1] 
             if expense.expense_url.present?      
                file = open("#{expense.expense_url}").read
                attachments["Expense#{expense.issue.name}_#{expense_number}_#{expense.date.to_date}.pdf"] = file
            end
        end
        mail subject: "Reminder"
    end    
end
```

reminder.html.erb

```
<% @expenses.each do |expense|%>
    Expense No.: <%= expense.description.split(' ')[1] %>  
    <br />
    Current expense total: <%= expense.value %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is any HTML being generated inside the @ expenses block? Have you checked to see what the value of @ expenses is in the html.erb file?

Comment: @Mark outside the block